# Is it tenable to access file metadata using flowgear resources?

Tags: flowgear

I have a requirement use a flowgear workflow to process files (via a droppoint, targeting an windows file share [SMB]), but targeting only the files that have been modified after a certain time of day.

How can one tell the the "Last Modified" date/time of a file using a flowgear node?

I have been searching the [Flowgear help center](https://help.flowgear.net/en/), and have been experimenting with file-related nodes - File, File Enumerator, File Watcher and File Manage, but I haven't seen any property that exposes this piece of metadata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can do it.

https://flowgear.me/#s/cCp8kGQ

In this sample, you simply use the script to get a list of files, after that you can once again use the normal File nodes to do the rest. It can be modified to return the file directly via the Script node, however that would require additional hand-coding and is needlessly complex.